# ImageCollection (Error) Parameter 'index' is required

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to calculate a index of monthly EVI from modis dataset, but am receiving a "Parameter 'index' is required" error. I have found another answer about the question, but it doesn't work.

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-qsz/assets/Boreal_merge");

// import dataset
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD09GA_006_EVI')
  .filterDate('2003-01-01', '2011-12-31');
  
var clippedCollection = collection.map(function(image){
  return image.clip(table);
});
print('rawdata', clippedCollection);

// calculate monthly average EVI
var monthlyMean = function(year, month) {
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1);
  var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'month');

  var monthlyImages = clippedCollection.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .mean()
    .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis());

  return monthlyImages;
};

var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);
print(months);
var monthlyEvi = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  ee.List.sequence(2003, 2011).map(function(year){
    return months.map(function(month){
      var evi = monthlyMean(year, month);
      var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1);
      var evi2 = evi.set('system:time_start', startDate);
      return evi2.set('month', month);
    });
  }).flatten()
);
print('Monthly EVI', monthlyEvi);

//visualize
var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'ce7e45', 'df923d', 'f1b555', 'fcd163', '99b718', '74a901',
    '66a000', '529400', '3e8601', '207401', '056201', '004c00', '023b01',
    '012e01', '011d01', '011301'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(-7.03125, 31.0529339857, 2);
Map.addLayer(formattedEvi, colorizedVis, 'Colorized');

//test
var testyear = 2008;
var eviYear = monthlyEvi.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(testyear, testyear, 'year'));

// calculate index d
var d = ee.Number(2).multiply(Math.PI).divide(12);
print('d',d);
// calculate cos term
var costerm = ee.List.sequence(0, 11).map(function(i){
  return (d.multiply(i)).cos(); 
});
print('cos', costerm.get(0));

var mx_col =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
     months.map(function(month) {
     var eviMonth = eviYear.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month)).first();
     var L = eviMonth.select('EVI');
     var mx = L.multiply(ee.Number(costerm.get(month-1)));
     return mx.set('system:time_start', eviMonth.get('system:time_start'));
   }).flatten()
  );

print('mx_col', mx_col);
```

When I output every variable such as mx, L, etc. outside of the map function it outputs successfully, but when using the map loop and generating the imagecollection I get the error. I'm a beginner in GEE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
.
.
.
     var mx = L.multiply(ee.Number(costerm.get(month-1)));
.
.
.
```

Fixing as follows:

```
var mx = L.multiply(ee.Number(costerm.get(ee.Number(month).subtract(1))));
```

running my own version of [your code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/77a337ef51954925c58b34dd07c603e0) (your asset is unavailable), I got a result without any error.

Comment: Hi @xunilk, thank you very much! I modified the code the way you did and it works successfully!